# How to make a search in twitter api on python

Tags: python, twitter

I'm triying to make a search but I don't know how to pass the search parameters ,I've tried with a string  with the search url  but it gives  this error
`TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` ,what argument I have ti pass fot sarch tweets??

```
import funciones
import json


twitter_api = funciones.oauth_login()

busqueda = twitter_api.search.tweets("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=python&src=typd")
```